# Prevent css interact in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am doing a code that do some js injection of code in page, with JQuery. But in my input that i get in some pages modify it, I am putting all important attributes and define them as !important, but it's impossible to put all the attributes in all the tags.

Someone know how to disable all other css inside a div?

Solution I think:
I found a solution but i don't want to use it. Its eliminate al css from the page, while i am injecting the code after using that code I eliminate my css and code and apply the original code from the webpage

Thanks

Comment: We need some code, because frankly...I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: U want code from the css? or JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you override everything it will work with normal CSS rules on every page. Not what you were hoping for, but it is *a* solution.

**css**:

```
#myInsertDiv { 
    color: blue;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: white;
    border: 0px;
    /* etc you have to restyle EVERY possible value */
}
```

**html**:
`<div id="myInsertDiv"></div>`

The main issue is you have to style **every** attribute, and reset everything else to a default value.

Or you can insert all the style information into the `style` attribute on the div, but that is probably doing it wrong too.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using that many `!important`s you're doing it wrong.
The solution to this problem is to properly organize your css. Important stuff last, because it overrides what was previously styled. Also use your selectors wisely. Example:

```
<a class="link">Link</a>
```

.

```
a:link { color: red; }
.
.
.
.link { color: green !important; } // Nop

a.link { color: green; } // Yup
```

Comment: Oh yes, but the problem its that I have no control of the previously styled, I am injecting code in pages that I don't know them

Comment: So you're debuggin' css with devtools or something like that?

Comment: Yes but its complex because this its a script that runs in bookmark. You save it as bookmark and run it. But if you run it in google.com google affect with some styles. but if you run it in Facebook it affect different

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right you can use jQuery for modifying CSS properties on any elements of the page (huh), using something like this `$('.Myclass').css('color','#ff0000')`

And more about selectors in jQuery - http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/